Plotly - scatter markers - assign a chosen color
Here's the code I'm trying to get working:
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

Prod=[450000, 500000, 420000,300000]
colors = ['rgb(215,209,209)','rgb(170,170,170)', 'rgb(115,115,115)','rgb(67,67,67)']
fig = make_subplots(rows=1, cols=2, column_widths=\[0.85,0.15\]

for i in range(4):
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=\[0,0,0,0\],y=Prod, name="Total Year", marker=dict(
    color=colors[i],
    size=12)), row=1, col=2)

It only takes in consideration the last color of the colors list.
Can you help me please? I've seen some tutorial but it happens that the used trick is often too apply colors from a column of a dataframe which is not my case.
ps: As you can see, the plot is a simple vertical line, I did not see anywhere a dedicated plot.

Your code handles 4 data points in a loop process and the marker color is set to one color depending on the index. So you are overwriting everything with 4 data point colors. If I were to modify your code, would I add an index to the list of y-axes? Or stop the loop processing and just have a list of colors.

for i in range(4):     fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(         x=[0,0,0,0],         y=[Prod[i]],         name="Total Year",         marker=dict(color=colors[i], size=12)     ), row=1, col=2)

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(     x=[0,0,0,0],     y=Prod,     name="Total Year",     marker=dict(color=colors, size=12) ), row=1, col=2)
